# Arduino Uno debugging

Tags: arduino, gdb, qt-creator, avr, gdbserver

I'm absolutely new to microcontroller development and currently want to:

1. Understand a typical process of the development
2. Set I/O and tune all tools for the development.

Currently I'm using Arduino Uno (ATmega328 based)

- I found PlatformIO. It looks useful for me to work with microcontrollers on different platforms
- [Qt Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) is a favorite IDE, and I'd prefer to continue using this for AVR programming (PlatformIO can also generate Qt Creator's project template)

I've tried to build and run first sketch there, it works. So the only question is still there is a debugging.

Correct me if I'm wrong, two primary ways to do this is a JTAG and debugWire, and both ones are "hardware" debug, correct? And, of course, require additional devices.

In other hand, Qt Creator has a "bare metal" plugin which can work (debug) with a devices who can "behaves" as gdbserver.

I also found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1037057/Debugger-for-Arduino) where the author suggests own implementation for a library for an Arduino project, which emulates gdbserver for a PC GDB client via the usual serial connection. Of course, I'll try this way as a preferable in my case.

So the question is - please confirm that all assumptions are correct.
And probably someone uses this way (maybe without this IDE).